# Kids with french fries or potatoes for hair?

Tags: story-identification

I think it was from an anthology pre or circa 1978. Might have been Stanislaw Lem but I couldn't find anything searching his work. The kids had french fries for hair. I was 8 and that is all I remember. We read a lot of Hugo and Nebula anthologies at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lem's *Star Diaries*, the twenty-fifth voyage includes an encounter with spacefaring potatoes.  But they aren't potato-human hybrids.  They're descended from ordinary potatoes which were stranded on an isolated planet.

Comment: Wrong but a nice connection Paul. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot, but could it be Burger Creature by Steve Chapman? The story is from 1973 and it was in The Year’s Best Horror Stories: Series III in 1975 so the timing is about right.

The story is told from the perspective of a lady working in a fast food restaurant. One day she hears a knock at the back door and discovers:

> It looked
>   like a tall, stringy man made of gritty, burnt hamburger meat in jeans, track sneakers, and a dirty undershirt. Its hair was a tangle of french fries. Its mouth, a wedge of onion smeared around the edges with ketchup. Its eyes were pickle slices, and it had no nose.

So it isn't children with french fries for hair. But this is the only even vaguely similar story I could find.

Comment: Thanks John! It is indeed "Burger Creature". I even found it at Amazon in a paperback  anthology called "Orbits 12".